# Editing Refactoring snippet for C# in Visual Studio 2015, doesn't change the refactoring behaviour?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, code-snippets

I want to change the typical property generation from outputting this:

```
set
{
    amountOfDogesValue = value;
}
```

to outputting something like this:

```
set
{
    if (value > 0)
        amountOfDogesValue = value;
    else
        throw new System.ArgumentException("Parameter cannot be smaller than 0", "DogesAmount");
}
```

(**but**) with some elements that don't compile, in the if clause and throw line, so I can never ever forget to edit them.

I use Visual Studio 2015 and have edited C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Refactoring\EncapsulateField.snippet

and restarted MVS, and rebooted the pc.

Yet somehow it still refactors **exactly** the same way as before.

Here's my code for EncapsulateField.snippet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>Encapsulate Field</Title>
            <Description>Refactoring snippet for Encapsulate field</Description>
            <Author>Microsoft Corporation</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Refactoring</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal Editable="true">
                    <ID>modifier</ID>
                    <Default>public</Default>
                </Literal>
                <Literal Editable="false">
                    <ID>type</ID>
                    <Default>type</Default>
                </Literal>
                <Literal Editable="false">
                    <ID>name</ID>
                    <Default>name</Default>
                </Literal>
                <Literal Editable="false">
                    <ID>field</ID>
                    <Default>field</Default>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="csharp">
                <![CDATA[

$modifier$ $type$ $name$
{
  get { return $field$; }
  set 
  { 
    if (value x= xm)
      $field$ = value;
    else
      throw new System.ArgumentException("Parameter cannot be "+, "$field$");
  }
}]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

(The x= xm is to remind me to change to the contextually correct operand and the +, is to remind me to edit the string before it.)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?