# VS throw new [System.]NotImplementedException(); instead of Using

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

VS 2017, in C#, when Coding ahead (i.e. typing in a function name that doesn't exist, and letting VS create it for you) it puts this line inside the method:

```
throw new NotImplementedException();
```

And in the using statements it adds this:

```
using System;
```

The problem is that I'm in Unity, and using Unity's Random function, but System.Random keeps taking over/confusing it.  I.e. I do NOT want using System; added.  I'm running into this about 5-20 times a day, and would like to get rid of it.

Is there any way in VS 2017, that when I have it code ahead/Build a method for me, that I can have it **not** add the using statement, and instead insert the line:

```
 throw new System.NotImplementedException();
```

Instead?

- Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you change your reference to your Random variables / properties etc to include the unity namespace so it doesn't matter?

Comment: I thought the answer to this was [Code Snippets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-snippets), which are located in `<VS Install Location>\VC#\Snippets\1033\Refactoring`. However, when I tried editing the `MethodStub.snippet` to test before posting an answer I couldn't get Visual Studio to use the change, even after restarting VS. Another answer talks about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41299349/editing-refactoring-snippet-for-c-sharp-in-visual-studio-2015-doesnt-change-th. Maybe you'll have better luck getting the change to stick.

Comment: I had the same result on snippet editing.  Visual studio didn't accept any of my changes.

Comment: Anyone ever figure this out? It's such a major pain